# Unknown column 'Student_Name' in 'field list' in codeigniter Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/codeIgniter/CodeIgniter-3.1.4/system/database/DB_driver.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter. I have a form which enters data in a database but I'm facing a problem here saying "Unknown column `Student_Name` in `field list` in codeigniter". I have tried but I can't solve it so far.

Here is my code.

**View file
`Userinsert_view.php`**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<?php echo form_open('Userinsert_controller'); ?>
<h1>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter</h1><hr/>
<?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
<CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER><br>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo form_label('Student Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dname'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Student Email :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('demail'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Student Mobile No. :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dmobile'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dmobile', 'name' => 'dmobile', 'placeholder' => '10 Digit Mobile No.')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Student Address :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('daddress'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'daddress', 'name' => 'daddress')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>
<div id="fugo">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller file
`Userinsert_controller.php`**

```
<?php

class Userinsert_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Userinsert_model');
    }

    function index() {
        //Including validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

        //Validating Name Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');

        //Validating Email Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('demail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        //Validating Mobile no. Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dmobile', 'Mobile No.', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');

        //Validating Address Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('daddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('Userinsert_view');
        } else {
            //Setting values for tabel columns
            $data = array(
                'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
                'Student_Email' => $this->input->post('demail'),
                'Student_Mobile' => $this->input->post('dmobile'),
                'Student_Address' => $this->input->post('daddress')
            );
            //Transfering data to Model
            $this->Userinsert_model->form_insert($data);
            $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            //Loading View
            $this->load->view('Userinsert_view', $data);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**Model file
`Userinsert_model.php`**

```
<?php

class Userinsert_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function form_insert($data){
        // Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
        $this->db->insert('students', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to match the field name in your database.  Check whether it has capital or not. Pass the exact field name you have in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake in passing values to desired database columns. Make sure **$data** array's key exist with same column name in database table:

```
 $data = array( 'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('dname'), 'Student_Email' => $this->input->post('demail'), 'Student_Mobile' => $this->input->post('dmobile'), 'Student_Address' => $this->input->post('daddress') );
```

You are passing the value in **Student_name** index and it must be present in the table. Careful about case sensitive column names.

Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: oo yess!! you were absolutely spot on!! Thankyou very much @abhishek singh

Comment: Welcome Buddy!!